# When code hits exception case program immidiately stops, need program to reprompt the user after exception throw

Tags: c#

I need the program to continue and prompt the user for a new value after an exception throw.

Program throws a run time error when hitting the exception, says it is unhandled

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
class SwimmingWaterTemperature
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Your code here
        int temp = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature or type 999 to quit");
        do
        {
            temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            bool comfort = CheckComfort(temp);
        }
        while (temp != 999);

    }

    public static bool CheckComfort(int temp)
    {
        // your logic here   
            bool comfort;
            if (temp >= 70 && temp <= 85)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees is comfortable for swimming.", temp);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter another temperature or 999 to quit");
            comfort = true;
                return comfort;
            }
            else if ((temp >= 32 && temp <= 70) || (temp >= 85 && temp <= 212) && temp != 999)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees is not comfortable for swimming.", temp);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter another temperature or 999 to quit");
            comfort = false;
                return comfort;
            }
            else if (temp == 999)
            {
            comfort = false;
            return comfort;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Value does not fall within expected range");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter another temperature or 999 to quit");
        }

    }
}
```

"Runtime error, unhandled exception"

Comment: Then i have found the site for you! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

A common rule of thumb is: **Exceptions should be exceptional**.

You should never, ever, use exceptions for control flow, we have a lot of other constructs that are better for that. There's absolutely no surprise if the user inputs something invalid, that's a valid usage of your application, so the application should not treat the case where the user goes off script as unexpected. In fact, you can expect it and test for it.

So, in your case, it's much, much better to refactor the code.

1. You know that 999 is the quit command (that can also be done better, but lets keep it)
2. You know that the valid range is 32 to 212, so you can have a method
   that checks that.

---

Something along these lines is a much better approach:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Your code here
    int temp = 0;
    do
    {
        // we can do at the start of every loop, no need to have the same code in multiple places
        Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature or type 999 to quit");
        temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        // no need to do additional processing if we got the quit sequence
        if (temp != 999) {
            // and here we KNOW that we are not in a quit sequence

            // now check if the entered value is valid
            bool isValid = CheckValidTemperature(temp);

            if (isValid) {
                // here we KNOW that the temperature is in the valid range
                bool comfort = CheckComfort(temp);
                if (comfort) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees is comfortable for swimming.", temp);
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Degrees is not comfortable for swimming.", temp);
                }
            } else {
                // here we KNOW that the temperature in NOT in the valid range
                // no need for exceptions, we just show a message
                Console.WriteLine("Value does not fall within expected range");
            }
        }
    }
    while (temp != 999);
}

public static bool CheckValidTemperature(int temp)
{
    // the range 32 - 212 is valid, everything else is invalid
    return (temp >= 32 && temp <=212);
}

public static bool CheckComfort(int temp)
{
    // your logic here - no need to validate anything, as we know that it is valid
    // however, we could validate here, and if it's invalid now, that would indeed be exceptional

    //if (!CheckValidTemperature(temp)) {
    //  // quite ok to throw here, as this should never happen under normal circumstances
    //  throw new ArgumentException("Value does not fall within expected range");
    //}

    // this can be some complicated logic
    if (temp >= 70 && temp <= 85)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'll leave the case when the user enters something that is not a number at the prompt as a extension that will need to be implemented :D

Comment: A common rule of thumb is: Exceptions should be exceptional. Could you explain/elucidate the being followed, sir?

Comment: [Exactly what it says on the tin](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin). You should always be surprised when you get an exception. Things that can be expected, should be checked and guarded against.

Answer (score -2):

```cs
try
{
    throw new System.ArgumentException();
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value does not fall within the expected range.");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another temperature or 999 to quit");
    comfort = false;
    return comfort;
}
```

Comment: You should never do this.